# dynamically searching in json data

Tags: json, angular, typescript

what I am trying here is to use the variables i read off the route to determine which blog to use from the json. the json file is an array of sections which further contain an array of blogs.

while the code runs perfectly if i put id1 and id2 as 1, 2 in the `this.blog=data[this.id1].blogs[this.id2];` line,

I am getting an error `TypeError:_data_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___namespace[this.id1] is undefined` on no change.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as data from '../data.json';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  id1;
  id2;
  sub;
  blog;
  
  constructor(
    private _Activatedroute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private _router: Router
  ) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._Activatedroute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
      this.id1 = Number(params.get('id1'));
      this.id2 = Number(params.get('id2'));
      this.blog = data[this.id1].blogs[this.id2];
    });
  }
}
```

also on replacing id1, id2 with any variable, i get the same error.

**edit:** I changed the `import * as data from '../data.json';` to `const data=require('../data.json');` and i got the correct result. however, i still dont understand why this happens and would like to keep the question open for same.

Comment: and why would you do that? you can make an async call (from assets folder) to the json file and load the data so you have a reduced bundle size!

Comment: how do you get `data` object ? in your code `data` should be undefined since it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: What is `params` holding when log it into console? can you share it?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti it displays the correct values of id1 and id2 as obtained from the url.

Comment: @micronyks it is in the second line of the code

Comment: "also on replacing id1, id2 with any variable, i get the same error." -  You said `if i put id1 and id2 as 1, 2` then it is working!

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti yes, if i write ,`blog=data[0].blogs[0]` it works correctly, but when i do `t=0; blog=data[t].blogs[t]` it shows that error.

Answer (score 0):

`params.get` method returns only string. You can try converting it into number before passing it to data.

Comment: i did! in the `this.id1 = Number(params.get('id1'));
      this.id2 = Number(params.get('id2'));` lines

Comment: Try this out ```import data from '../data.json';```

Comment: Post you ```RouterModule``` json here if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the line written below

```
this.blog = data[+this.id1].blogs[+this.id2];
```

Comment: write down your activated url in comment

Comment: you have only declared id1 and id2. try to initialize with some initial values.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.